# xsl - Return Multiple Nodes as Comma Separated

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, foreach

I am creating an XSL stylesheet to convert an XML file to pre-formatted Excel. In one of the columns is the CCI_REF below. However, there can be multiple CCI_REF numbers per Vuln_Num, as you can see below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CHECKLIST>
 <STIGS>
  <iSTIG>
   <VULN>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Vuln_Num</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>V-1070</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-000192</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-000193</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
    <STIG_DATA>
     <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
     <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-000194</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
    </STIG_DATA>
   </VULN>
  </iSTIG>
 </STIGS>
</CHECKLIST>
```

I tried using an xsl:for-each, but it actually isn't returning anything now. I'm guessing it is the reference in the for-each line, but I've tried every combination I can think of and haven't made a difference. Abbreviated XSL:

```
<xsl:call-template name="front_page" />
<Worksheet>
 <xsl:attribute name="ss:Name">
  <xsl:value-of select="$vhostname" />
 </xsl:attribute>
 <Table>
  <xsl:for-each select="STIGS/iSTIG/VULN">
  <xsl:sort select="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE[node()='Rule_Ver']/../ATTRIBUTE_DATA" order="ascending" />
  <Row>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="stig_rules"> <!-- VMS Key -->
    <Data ss:Type="String">
    <xsl:value-of select="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE[node()='Vuln_Num']/../ATTRIBUTE_DATA" />
    </Data>
   </Cell>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="stig_rules"> <!-- CCI Number -->
    <Data ss:Type="String">
     <xsl:for-each select="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE/CCI_REF">
      <xsl:value-of select="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE[node()='CCI_REF']/../ATTRIBUTE_DATA" />
     <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </Data>
   </Cell>
  </Row
 </Table>
</Worksheet>
```

Thanks. Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you have is with this line...

```
<xsl:for-each select="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE/CCI_REF">
```

`CCI_REF` is not an element in your XML, but just a text node, so you want to handle in much the same way as you do on the next line

```
<xsl:for-each select="STIG_DATA/VULN_ATTRIBUTE[text() = 'CCI_REF']">
```

In fact, you could simplify it to this

```
 <xsl:for-each select="STIG_DATA[VULN_ATTRIBUTE = 'CCI_REF']">
```

This would then make it slightly easier to get the `ATTRIBUTE_DATA` value, but doing just this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_DATA" />
```

For example, try this XSLT

```
<Worksheet>
 <Table>
  <xsl:for-each select="STIGS/iSTIG/VULN">
  <xsl:sort select="STIG_DATA[VULN_ATTRIBUTE = 'Rule_Ver']/ATTRIBUTE_DATA" order="ascending" />
  <Row>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="stig_rules"> <!-- VMS Key -->
    <Data ss:Type="String">
    <xsl:value-of select="STIG_DATA[VULN_ATTRIBUTE = 'Vuln_Num']/ATTRIBUTE_DATA" />
    </Data>
   </Cell>
   <Cell ss:StyleID="stig_rules"> <!-- CCI Number -->
    <Data ss:Type="String">
     <xsl:for-each select="STIG_DATA[VULN_ATTRIBUTE = 'CCI_REF']">
      <xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE_DATA" />
     <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </Data>
   </Cell>
  </Row>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </Table>
</Worksheet>
```